# Is there any async driver/module for MySQL which can be used on Tornado to support transactions?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, tornado

Is there any async driver/module for MySQL which can be used on Tornado to support transactions ?
I am writting Tornado app with MySQL as database. I have googled and found
https://github.com/woshifyz/tornado-mysql

https://github.com/hybridlogic/txMySQL

but there is no support for transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado's own database module supports transactions just fine.

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
                    (r'/', someHandler),
                   ]

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

        self.db = tornado.database.Connection(
            host=mysql_host, database=mysql_db,
            user=mysql_user, password=mysql_password)

# ----------------------

class someHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # ...

        try:
            self.application.db.execute('START TRANSACTION')
            row = self.application.db.get("SELECT ...", ...)
            # ...
            self.application.db.execute("INSERT ...", ...)
            self.application.db.execute("COMMIT")
        except Exception, e:
            self.set_status(500)
            return

        # ...
```

However, it doesn't support async calls.

**UPDATE (May 2015)**

Several updates to the topic.

1. Tonado's DB driver was excluded from the project. It is available as a separate library named **torndb** (available [here](https://github.com/bdarnell/torndb)).
2. These projects might be of interest: [TorMySQL](https://github.com/snower/TorMySQL), [Tornado-MySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/Tornado-MySQL), [AsyncTorndb](https://github.com/mayflaver/AsyncTorndb).